# martial arts for SLE Patient

Tags: health, martial-arts

I'm 26 and it's about 5 years that i have SLE. I wander what is good martial art for not only gain fitness and good for my health but be good for self-defense?
thanks.

Comment: What's SLE?  Is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemic_lupus_erythematosus or something else here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLE

Comment: yes .it is Systemic_lupus_erythematosus. but my condition is at the minimum level.